# How to answer skeptic who points to latent variable?

Tags: multiple-regression, p-value, latent-variable

I have a linear model with the following form:

$$
y = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2
$$

As $y$ is considered a "moral" behavior, I expect resistance and skepticism of the following kind:

- the sole cause of $y$ is the permanently latent variable $x_3$.
- $y$ does not depend on $x_1$ or $x_2$ in any way.
- ***$x_1$ and $x_2$ neither cause $y$, nor do they cause $x_3$!!***
- ***$x_3$ does not cause either $x_1$ or $x_2$!!***
- $x_1$ and $x_2$ routinely show chance strong correlations with both $y$ and $x_3$.
- yes, $x_3$ is the sole cause of $y$ (there is no other latent variable).

E.g., AOK = monthly number of Acts of Kindness with a specific coding process.

$$
AOK = \beta_0 + \beta_1Parents' AOK + \beta_2Best friend's AOK
$$
$$
x_3 = "Individual Moral Kindness"
$$

I reply:

- The p-values of $x_1$ and $x_2$ are both <0.01, suggesting there is less than a 1 in 100 chance that the connection between them and $y$ is a product of chance.
- If I independently replicate this study 10 times with the same results, it is more likely that your sandwich flies off the table like a bird than it is that random chance shows this relationship between $y$ and $x_1$ and $x_2$.
- are you really claiming that $x_3$ is the sole cause of $y$?

**In the role of frequentist statistician, what better reply can I give in our conceptual disagreement about the role of $x_3$?**

**What would be a good reply from the frequentist statistician if the skeptic tried to strengthen their case by saying: If we could measure $x_3$, you would see that even if your p-values stay the same, $x_3$ explains 99.999%, so $x_1$ and $x_2$ are meaningless even if statistically significant?**

Comment: Are you conflating association with causation here? There are all sorts of reasons why two variables may be associated that are not causal.

Comment: @Glen_b: I will have to write that ("why two variables..") as another question (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141253/can-two-variables-be-perfectly-correlated-but-not-share-a-single-causal-chain-an). I think $x_1$ is at least correlated with $y$, but then I want to say: you can't assign all causal power to $x_3$ because if $x_1$ not a cause, then there is some latent variable(s) $X_4$ with some causal power over $x_1$ and $y$ too. Sorry if unclear!